# Some calculation about expectation of empirical CDF

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics

Given iid random samples $X_1,\dots, X_n$ with CDF $F(x)$ and $f(x)$ that is continuous and symmetric around $0$. (Then $E X=0$ and 50% quantile is $0$). Define the empirical CDF as
$F_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n I(X_i\le x)$.

How to simplify the following expectation in terms of $\mu_k=E|X_1|^k$ for $k=1,2,...$?

(1)
$$
 E\left[|X_1|^2(2F_n(0)-1)^2\right]
$$
(2)
$$
 E[X_1|X_1|(2F_n(0)-1)]
$$

For (1),
This becomes
$$
E\left[4|X_1|^2F_n(0)^2+|X_1|^2-4F_n(0)|X_1|^2\right]=E[4|X_1|^2F_n(0)^2]+E[|X_1|^2]-4E[F_n(0)|X_1|^2]
$$
where the third term is $4E[I(X_1\le 0)|X_1|^2]=4*0.5*\mu_2=2\mu_2$, and the first term is

$$
4E\left[|X_1|^2\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}I(X_i\le 0, X_j\le 0)\right)\right]
$$
but I am stuck here...

For (2), since $E[X_1|X_1|]=0$, it becomes
$$
E[2X_1|X_1|F_n(0)]=2E[X_1|X_1|I(X_1\le 0)]=-2\int_0^\infty x|x|dF(x)=-\mu_2
$$
Does this one correct?